# Div near div container

Tags: css, html

[image: http://s6.ifotos.pl/img/Beztytuuj_nxsqrns.jpg]

I create pic what i must do this. I have div container page. And i now on top div creating div to login and register page . And i want div what have login and register form have posttion near top div. How to do what? I tryed float: left and right posstion absolute fixed relative and nothing help. 
My div container css

```
#srodek
{
margin:0 auto;
width: 970px;
}
```

and div login

```
#logowanie
{
border-style:dotted;
border-width:2px;
display:none;
float:left;
padding:8px;
}
```

Comment: can u create sample on jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PPHNK/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using javascript to make the login box visible, the position of this login box
can be dynamically given as:

```
$("#logo").on("click", function () {
    alert("test");

    $("#logowanie").css({
        "display": "block",
      "left":$("#srodek").offset().left + 
          970
      + "px"
    });
});
```

Here is the working copy: http://jsbin.com/efeler/1

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure what you are asking for but I think you are trying to position some div tags. So when you have your container, let's say 600 x 600 px, if you want to place 3 boxes (div tags) in the top row at 200 px a piece, then your code should use the display:inline-block; in the css form to lock in the div tags where they should be.

so:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="box1"></div>
     <div class="box2"></div>
     <div class="box3"></div>
</div>

.container{
     width:600px;
     height:600px;

.box1
     width:200px;
     height:200px;
     display:inline-block;

.box2
     width:200px;
     height:200px;
     display:inline-block;

.box3
     width:200px;
     height:200px;
     display:inline-block;
```